# how to avoid the disadvantages of positional arguments in php's functions?

Tags: php, function, arguments, optional-arguments

I have some php functions that have a huge number of parameters with default values. Something like this:

```
function foo($a=0,$b=6,$c=2,...
```

I wonder what can I do to avoid the horrors of positional arguments. Is it possible to call the function with just a subset of the arguments set, and by name? As in:

```
foo($c=37)
```

thanks!

Comment: No it isn't, and there's been a lot of debate about this among the PHP Internals... the only real workround is an associative array, with an extract() in the function

Comment: instead of passing one by one variable, pass arguments in array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I absolutely understand where this question is comming from, but I must say: if your function requires a series of arguments, that are optional, 9/10 there's something wrong with your function.
A function in real life is *the ability to do something*. In the real world, a chair is something to sit on. It can have *N* legs, but it does a single job. In a lot of code I've seen over time, functions that have too many optional arguments do different tasks, depending on what arguments are passed to it. Thus, that function has more than 1 task. That's *not* what functions are for!

Rethink your logic, please. If, however your function does a single job, irrespective of which arguments are specified @OZ_'s answer is the one to go for: type-hinting (via Class-name or interface) is the *right* way to do this.
Associative arrays would work, too, *but* to avoid having to write a ton of `if`'s like:

```
$a = 'default';
if (isset($args['a']))
{
    $a = $args['a'];
}
$b = isset($args['b']) ? $args['b'] : 'default';//or messy ternary-packed code
```

you might choose to write something like this:

```
function someF(array $args)
{
    $a = $b = $c = $d = null;//all your arguments and default values
    foreach($args as $name => $val)
    {
        $$name = $val;
    }
    //function body
}
someF(range(1,3));//works, but sets ${'0'}, ${'1'}, ...
someF(array('a' => 1));//works fine
someF(array('a' => new stdClass));//is $a going to be the right type?
```

Still, as in the `if`'s/ternary approach, You can't predict which types the values will be, nor do you know what type of array is being passed (assoc/numeric) so you might end up setting lots of variables you don't need. Plus, would you call this code easy to read/debug/maintain a couple of months from now?

Using a class, or interface, on the other hand:

```
class ArgumentsForFunc
{
    private $a = null;
    private $email = null;
    public function setA($val = null)//defaults to default value...
    {
        $this->a = $val === null ? null : (int) $val;//cast to correct type
        return $this;
    }
    public function getA()
    {
        return $this->a;
    }
    public function setEmail($email = null)
    {
        if (!$email || !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        {//check data here!
            $email = null;
            //or better yet:
            throw new InvalidArgumentException((string) $email.' is not a vaild email address');
        }
        $this->email = $email;
        return $this;
    }
    public function getEmail($default = null)
    {
        return $this->email ? : $default;
    }
}
```

This class's job is clear: it holds the data, which it receives through setters. These setter methods validate the raw data, and can throw exceptions or cast to the correct type. This means you can use it like so:

```
function betterF(ArgumentsForFunc $args)
{
    $a = $args->getA();
    $email = $args->getEmail('default@email.arg');
    echo 'send ', $a, ' mails to ', $email;
}
$arg = new ArgumentsForFunc;
$arg->setA(2);
betterF($arg);//send 2 mails to default@email.arg
```

Now you can rest assured that, as long as the user passes an instance of `ArgumentsForFunc`, your function will behave as you expected to. Of course, this approach requires you to write a bit more code initially, but it'll save you tons of trouble debugging, and makes testing a lot easier.

PS: throw exceptions in data-models. If the data that is being set is invalid, notify the user ASAP. When an exception is thrown as soon as the setter is called, you can easily trace the bug. If you don't (and silently fail), you can spend hours on end trying to work out why your `getEmail` call is returning `null`, and not the email address you thought you passed to the setter somewhere else.

Comment: What if I'm using a standard function like [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)? I might want to use this function with a $maxlen of 1 to just see if a link returns an okay HTTP status code or not. I then would have to give the default values for three further arguments I don't care for!

Comment: @ConstantinBerhard: Yes, you'd have to write `file_get_contents('/path/to/file', false, -1, null, 1);`. At least, for now. There have been talks about supporting named parameters in PHPNG (upcomming PHP7 release), in which would allow you to write `file_get_contents($filename = '/path/to/file', $maxlen = 1);` You _can_ implement this feature already (using a wrapper function that takes an assoc array or something), but I'd pass all the arguments as-is, and wait for what PHP-NG (release planned for November this year)

Answer (score 9):

**Apparently the best way**  to avoid the horrors of positional arguments is to **avoid functions with long and windy arguments list.**

Either you can pass most of the parameters via **single array variable** or you need to refactor your functions splitting them into smaller ones or combining them in a **class**

Answer (score 1):

Not yet. Functions with number of parameters can be replaced by function with one argument, data structure (in php it's class without methods and with public fields).

```
function foo(FooSet $fooSet){
}

class FooSet{
 public $a = 0;
 public $b = 6;
 public $c = 2 ;
}
```

And don't use arrays for this - it's a bad practice called 'array oriented programming'.

Answer (score 1):

If you have *so* many parameters why not use an object and [__invoke](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.invoke) for it:

```
class FuncClass {

    public $a = 4;
    public $b = 4;
    public $c = 4;
    public $d = 4;
    ...

    function __invoke() {
    }

}
```

Use:

```
$func = new FuncClass();
$func->a = 3;
$func();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use named arguments in PHP.

Use an array as a single parameter and put your actual parameters in the array.

```
$arguments["a"]=1;
$arguments["b"]=2;
$arguments["c"]=3;


function args_test($arguments) {
   extract($arguments);
   echo $a.$b.$c;
}
```

args_test($arguments) will output 123.

at the beginning of your function will allow you to use them as proper parameters

Comment: @OZ_ it's a way of avoiding having to change all the function code

Comment: @OZ_ Thanks for pointing them out! Because he will obviously be calling his function with $_GET or $_FILES!

You answer is cleaner though and I will use it from now on. Thanks